# Why was this closed? (And should it be reopened?)

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I have come across this question in review, in the Reopen Queue:

[Why do we say “I would appreciate it if you paid in cash,” but not “I will appreciate it if you pay in cash”? [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318402/why-do-we-say-i-would-appreciate-it-if-you-paid-in-cash-but-not-i-will-appre)

It was closed as off-topic, but I'm not sure why. It has positive votes, and a semblance of research, so I'm curious about why it is regarded as off topic.

1. What is off topic about it, and
2. Should it be reopened?

Comment: Yeah, I can't see anything wrong with it. It was a while ago so unsure if the closers could really address their own reasons.

Comment: There were 4 reopen votes so I reopened the question.

Comment: While you're at it, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74502/it-would-be-better-if-you-drink-drank-all-the-water and take a look at the so-called duplicate, and please tell me if they are both the same question.

Comment: @Mari-Lou it might be deja vu but I think I skipped that in review for want of knowing what to do with it.

Comment: All the votes to close were "send it to ELL", but I can't see if it actually went and was rejected (which would certainly end up closed as off-topic), or if it was closed before that path was available (which would simply have closed it).

Comment: Ironically, this post led me to the question—which I just voted to close again as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Jason as long as the _right thing happens_, I don't mind if it's open or closed :)

Comment: I think both alternatives are possible in which case people might have reasoned that the premise is incorrect and the question invalid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > *All the votes to close were "send it to ELL", but I can't see if it actually went and was rejected (which would certainly end up closed as off-topic), or if it was closed before that path was available (which would simply have closed it).* – Andrew Leach♦
2. Now reopened.